# Conditional Resolve in Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, castle-windsor

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application. The default controller factory has been replaced by a WindsorControllerFactory as suggested [here](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-tutorial-ASP-NET-MVC-3-application-To-be-Seen.ashx). This is useful because the controllers in this app include references to a couple of services, which are instanciated using injection with Windsor. Each of the services have a proxy to wrap it.

Therefore, we have the following situation:

- Two components registered into Castle (one service and one proxy)
- One of them is constructed as a dependency of the other one

It looks something like:

```
// This URL can be resolved at application startup
container.Register(Component.For<ITestService>()
    .UsingFactoryMethod(() => ServiceFactory.CreateService<ITestService>(Settings.Default.ConfigurationProviderUrl))
    .Named(MainServiceComponent)
    .LifeStyle.Transient);

// The URL for this service can be configured during runtime. If it is null or empty it should not be resolved
container.Register(Component.For<ITestService>()
    .UsingFactoryMethod(() => ServiceFactory.CreateService<ITestService>(SiteInformation.PublishUrl))
    .Named(PublicationServiceComponent)
    .LifeStyle.Transient);

// This proxy is necessary
container.Register(Component.For<IConfigurationProxy>()
    .ImplementedBy<ConfigurationProxyWebService>()
    .ServiceOverrides(ServiceOverride.ForKey(typeof(ITestService)).Eq(MainServiceComponent))
    .LifeStyle.Transient);

// This proxy should be created only if SiteInformation.PublishUrl is different from empty or null
container.Register(Component.For<IConfigurationPublicationProxy>()
    .ImplementedBy<ConfigurationPublicationProxyWebService>()
    .ServiceOverrides(ServiceOverride.ForKey(typeof(ITestService)).Eq(PublicationServiceComponent))
    .LifeStyle.Transient);
```

Is there any way to make Windsor evaluate a condition before resolving? I know it has conditional registration, but I haven't found a way to make conditional resolving... Thank you in advance!

Comment: You say it "shouldn't be resolved" if a certain condition is met.  What does that mean though?  Do you want the resolution of that service to throw an exception, or do something else?

Comment: I mean if it could be resolved as null, so we can later check if the service has been created or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than returning a `null` reference (as you say in your comment), I'd instead return a [null service implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern). In other words, an implementation that is a no-op or just a passthrough. This way the class consuming the service doesn't need to add in any logic that it really should not know anything about (i.e. whether or not the service is valid to use in a given situation).

To do this, you can just use the `UsingFactoryMethod` functionality to make the decision of which service to return at runtime. Taking the first registration that you want to be conditional:

```
// The URL for this service can be configured during runtime. 
// If it is null or empty it should not be resolved.
container.Register(Component.For<ITestService>()
    .UsingFactoryMethod((kernel, context) => 
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SiteInformation.PublishUrl))
            return ServiceFactory.CreateService<ITestService>(
                SiteInformation.PublishUrl));
        return kernel.Resolve<INullTestService>();
    })
    .Named(PublicationServiceComponent)
    .LifeStyle.Transient);
```

I don't know what your `ITestService` interface looks like, but I'd make `INullTestService` derive from it, and the implementation do as little as possible.

Comment: Thanks! this was the way to go.